# How to set a local folder as the root folder using the base html element with no web url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-AU">

    <head>
    <base href="file:///EssixTechnology/" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    </head>
```

I'm trying to make a folder the base folder so i can reference to root like i did within the code for the javascript files source.

I'm looking to make my root folder the one all my files are contained in so when i upload it to any server the files will work without having to reference to a domain name which i do not have so i want all urls to work relative to the main folder which is *EssixTechnology* contained in the main folder is the `index.html` file which is where this code comes from.

The current code does not load the javascript file.

How do I set the base to be my folder "EssixTechnology"?

Comment: Also to add the reason im trying to do this is because i have nav bar html code contained in its own file and also sub html pages kept in a sub folder and when i load the nav html into a page that is contained in sub html folder it will have different url references eg imagine contact and location is in sub html the url links in the nav bar will not work because its in the folder below index.html that is why i need to define a root folder but it cannot be a web url!

Comment: Your code should work fine, but you are using a relative folder path. If you want the same base url for every sub folder, you might use an absolute path: `file:///C:/yourFolder/`. Maybe you can also consider a local running webserver to get rid of those file links.

Comment: but if i use an absolute file path then when i upload it to a server all the links will need to be changed i guess I need to set the base relative to my index file is that possible? my folder structure goes like this EssixTechnology/sub_html (folder)/ contact and location.html, css(folder)/stylesheet.css, index.html, javascriptfile this is probably a bit confusing how would i make the root relative to my index file?

Comment: If you actually want to upload it to a server you should definitely use a local installation of a webserver e.g. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html). If you upload it to a server, that server will be available via url and your whole file approach will fall apart.

Comment: So while i work  on it when it is in folders i should use the absolute file location in the base tag and then when i upload all ill have to do is change the base tag to the absolute url is that the best option? apologies if im not getting it im relatively new to this.. :)

Comment: ok so I tried  <base href="file:///D:/EssixTechnology/"/> and it still has not worked with the same code as above..

Comment: No matter I just figured out the root selector where you put / at the start of a url isnt necessary when using base as base sets your root folder for that page i guess the root selector is just unusable for me for some reason...

Comment: The `/` in front overwrites your base href tag. The `<base href="...">` does ONLY affect relative links (those not starting with a `/` or `http://`and so on). there is no way for html to change the root for your absolute urls. You would need some kind of URL-Rewrite for thath and this would again require a webserver.

Comment: Thanks for your answers appreciate it.